# Getting Template Errors When Using Cache Tag in some environments but not in others

Tags: cache

I'm having an issue where I am getting template errors related to my craft cache tags in some environments but not others. I have my site set up on a production server that is a Linode/Forge setup. The site works fine there.

Locally I am using a Homestead/Vagrant setup and I am getting template errors on any pages that use the cache tag.

Here's the code that is having the error:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}


{% block pageStyles %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('juices') %}
    .color-nameplate.btn-{{entry.slug}} {
        background-color: {{entry.productColorCode}};
    }
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

{% block bodyClass %}home-page{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

{% cache if craft.config.cache %}

{% for row in entry.bodyBuilder.level(1) %}
    {% include 'bodyblocks/' ~ row.type.handle with {row: row} %}
{% endfor %}

{% endcache %}

{% endblock %}
```

This code works in the production environment but not on local. On local it is showing the following template error:

> Unexpected token "name" of value "craft" ("end of statement block" expected).

If I remove the cache tags then the template displays, but this won't work for my production environment so I need to work out what the issue is.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 2):

So you're accessing `craft.config.cache` but unless you've actually added your own `cache` config setting in `craft/config/general.php` that's not going to work. There's no `cache` setting in Craft's [Config Settings](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings)

So the reason it works on `live` production is it's a soft error, and you have `devMode` off, so it continues to work. In `local` dev, presumably you have `devMode` on, so it rightly errors.

For more information on Craft cache tags, you can read the [The Craft {% cache %} Tag In-Depth](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-craft-cache-tag-in-depth) article.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to activate development mode under `craft/config/general.php`?